# How do we get Required RVR or Actual RVR for an instrument approach?

Tags: approach

When executing an instrument approach, when the pilot should start reference the RVR reported. Also, How do we get the required RVR for the current approach in execution and actual RVR. I think actual RVR can be part of METAR data. But I am not sure on the required RVR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current RVR is obtained from the METAR, yes, which in turn is obtained from [transmissometer(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runway_visual_range) on the airport site.

Minimum allowable RVR is obtained from charts ([chart legend from Jeppesen, PDF](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/documents/aviation/business/ifr-paper-services/intro-USA.pdf)), more specifically the [instrument approach plate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approach_plate) for approaching an airport. And on the [SID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_instrument_departure_(SID)) chart for departing.

Example:

[image]

R is RVR in hundreds of feet, V is Visibility in miles, in this example. Units can change and will be denoted, check full PDF for all examples.

Comment: RVR, in Europe at least, is broadcast by [ATIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Terminal_Information_Service#Example_1). Related [regulation](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Automatic_Terminal_Information_Service_(ATIS)). And also provided by ATC to assess the feasibility of an approach. RVR is applicable only when transmissometer are available at the airfield.

Comment: Thanks!. .Any idea when the pilot should start looking at the RVR data during the approach? During Final Approach Fix or later or earlier? What would the optimum instant to refer the RVR w.r.t airport field?

Comment: Thanks. Hm, the mixed default units for RVR seem pretty confusing to me. In the charts default is feet, and metres are written out when used (as confirmed by the linked pdf), while for METAR metres are default (R24/0300/N means 300 m) while feet are written out when used (e.g. R24/0900FT/N).